# How to remove @2x from image using the apple script

Tags: applescript

This script works as mentioned on a previous question to add @2x to all files in a folder, BUT how do I make or change this apple script to remove the @2x.

```
set appendable to "@2x"
set theFolder to choose folder
tell application "Finder"
    set theFiles to (files of entire contents of theFolder) as alias list
    repeat with theFile in theFiles
        set FileExtension to theFile's name extension as string
        set FileName to theFile's name as string
        set FileBaseName to text 1 thru ((offset of "." in FileName) - 1) of FileName
        set theFile's name to FileBaseName & appendable & "." & FileExtension
    end repeat
end tell
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tell application "Finder"
    repeat with f in (files of entire contents of (choose folder) as alias list)
        set n to name of f
        set x to name extension of f
        if n does not end with "@2x." & x then next
        set name of f to text 1 thru (-5 - (count x)) of n & "." & x
    end repeat
end tell
```

It would be easier to do it in a shell: `IFS=$'\n'; for f in $(find ~/Desktop -name '*@2x*'); do mv "$f" "${f//@2x/}"; done`.

Comment: AWESOME, that did the trick. I'm no master at scripting or terminal so thanks again!